# Smoothing the transition in a dropdown menu when class is swapped

Tags: jquery, css

### Objective

To create a smooth dropdown when the mobile navigation is expanded.

### Background

I currently have the prototype of a mobile navigation menu.

[image]

When you click on the menu, the mobile navigation "expands" by having the class swapped which has a `height: auto`

I did try adding transitions to the `.expanded` CSS class which ended up not working because it seems that the jQuery is just swapping the classes abruptly.

### Question

How can I tweek my CSS and/or jQuery to accomplish a smoother dropdown.

### Current State

I have the demo on [CodePen](http://codepen.io/JGallardo/pen/HIyGa)

#### HTML

```
<div class="nav-mobile-wrapper">
  <div class="collapsed">
    <nav class="nav-mobile">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="/trends">Trends<i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o ml6"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="/docs">Docs<i class="fa fa-file-o ml6"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="/images">Images<i class="fa fa-file-photo-o ml6"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="/videos">Videos<i class="fa fa-film ml6"></i></a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <a href="#" class="nav-mobile-button">Additional Resources <i class="fa fa-bars ml6"></i></a>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.nav-mobile-wrapper {
  width: 768px;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.collapsed {
  height: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.nav-mobile {
  background-color: #c0c0c0;
  background-image: url('https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/assets/noise-f1-99be850299aaf3f1e91225fa7a97228c.gif');
  width: 100%;
  text-align:right;
}
.nav-mobile-button {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #444;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 10px;
  color: #fff;
}
.nav-mobile ul {
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 30px;
  padding-left: 0;
}
.nav-mobile ul li {
  padding-right: 10px;
}
.nav-mobile ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  color: #333;
}
.nav-mobile ul li:hover {
  background-color: #ba222b;
}
.nav-mobile ul li a:hover {
  color: #f3f3f3;
}
.nav-mobile ul li:hover,
.nav-mobile ul li a:hover {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.25s ease;
  transition: all 0.25s ease;
}
.expanded {
  height: auto;
}
```

#### JS

```
$('.nav-mobile-wrapper').find('a[href="#"]').on('click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  this.expand = !this.expand;
  $(this).text(this.expand?"Close":"Menu");
  $(this).closest('.nav-mobile-wrapper').find('.collapsed, .expanded').toggleClass('collapsed expanded');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally like the jquery route with these sorts of things, here you go!

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Ejsbu

edit- switched to slideToggle(), even easier!

Comment: Ok so this eliminates the need for the wrapping `<div class="collapsed">` and the CSS. This definitely works well. Any thoughts on working with the text that is now not going to show? the "close"?